# PostgreSQL COPY FROM Command Help

Tags: database, postgresql, csv-import

I have CSV File which is quite large (few hundred MBs) which I am trying to import into Postgres Table, problem arise when there, is some primary key violation (duplicate record in CSV File)

If it has been one I could manually filter out those records, but these files are generated by a program which generate such data every hour. My script has to automatically import it to database.

My question is: Is there some way out that I can set a flag in COPY command or in Postgres so It can skip the duplicate records and continue importing file to table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My thought would be to approach this in two ways:

1. Use a utility that can help create an "exception report" of duplicate rows, [such as this one](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2010-05/msg00073.php) during the COPY process.
2. Change your workflow by loading the data into a temp table first, massaging it for duplicates (maybe JOIN with your target table and mark all existing in the temp with a dup flag), and then only import the missing records and send the dups to an exception table.

I personally prefer the second approach, but that's a matter of specific workflow in your case.

Comment: I'd go for the second solution as well (or use a different tool to load the data)

Comment: I'd go for the second solution

Comment: I tried @dawebber's second approach but as the database size increases per import, further imports are delayed and import time increases as the table grows.

Comment: @regexhacks, which part of the workflow is seeing a slowdown?